# Resize image thumbs relative to window size

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way that I can use jquery/css to resize my gallery thumb relatively screen size.
It mean image gallery fit to screen to all size of screen.

Lets say I have 1280x800 and the gallery fits in the screen.
But if I have 1024x768 I still want to fit the images in that screen.

I have images sitting like this

```
<div class="imageWrapper"> 
<img src="1.jpg" id="1"> 
<img src="2.jpg" id="3"> 
</div>
```

Till 70 images 
10 Images per row 
7 images per column

so if you resize the window I want them scale down according to the window size

Comment: I am sure it is possible. Put your draft code here please.

Comment: You should be able to do this with just CSS and image scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a code snippet that we can have a look at? It'll help us solve your problem.

For instance, if you have this:

```
<div>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
</div>
```

The solution could be something like

```
div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

But if your thumbnails have background-images in css, the solution could be something like this:

```
div.thumbnail {
    background-size: 100% 100%; /*works on FF4+ / IE9+ / Opera 10 / Safari 4.1+ / Chrome 3+ */
}
```

EDIT: If you want to have a bunch of images in rows, you can set them up as a grid, so you have html like this

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#"><img src="foo.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="foo.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="foo.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="foo.jpg"></a>
    ....
</div>
```

And CSS like this

```
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    zoom: 1; /*to clear the floats in IE*/
}
.gallery:after {
    content: "\0020"; /*an empty character*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.gallery a {
    float: left;
    width: 23%; /*This ones assumes 4 columns (25% - 1% each side for margins) */
    height: 100px; /*set it to something that makes sense for your gallery*/
    margin: 10px 1%; /*space between each thumbnail*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I just updated the answer to show you how you can set up a quick gallery layout.